# New-look Gmail - how to keep chat window visible over emails when minimised?

Tags: gmail, google-chat

Up till a week or two ago, if I had a chat open in Gmail it would sit over the top of the emails, and if minimised, would still remain there as a little bar.  It would turn blue if there was a new message.

Now, when looking at a chat, I do have an option to shrink it down so it sits over the top of emails, but if I minimise it then it disappears.

Does anyone know if it's possible to keep it minimised, still sitting over the emails?  It was really useful before, to keep it there, unobtrusive, whilst using email, being alerted when a new message came in, but now switching between chat and email has become a pain.

I can't find anything in Settings (the chat settings in particular) but I might be missing something.

Comment: Check https://support.google.com/chat/answer/9169357  also check "Manage chat settings" in Gmail settings "Chat and Meet" https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/chat

Comment: Please note that when I look at the feature, ongoing conversations become chat heads (circle icons) at bottom left when chats are minimized and new messages pop-out of those icons on receipt, with the option to click on message and restore chat window.

Comment: @BlindSpots I did notice (after a while) the little circle at the bottom left representing the chat.  That does help a bit.  There's nothing in the chat settings which seems to help, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: So, chat heads are on top of the email window and allow quick return to chat view.   They are unobtrusive, and whilst using email you get alerts when a new message comes in, and  switching between chat and email is not a pain. Is certainly a different implementation but seems to meets your needs.